# Can't get multiple jQuery gMap on same page

Tags: jquery-plugins

For some reason I can't get [gMap](http://gmap.nurtext.de/examples.html) to display multiple maps on the same page.

My setup is nearly identical to the examples, but just isn't working. I'm sure I'm missing something little.

Any thoughts?

Demo page here: http://play.artletic.com/jquery/gmaps.html

**jQuery:**

```
    $(function(){
 $("#map_1").gMap({
  controls: false,
  markers: [{ 
   address: "2844 Thornapple River Drive SE, Cascade, MI 49546",
   html: "Cascade" 
  }],
  address: "2844 Thornapple River Drive SE, Cascade, MI 49546",
  zoom: 9
 });

 $("#map_2").gMap({
  controls: false,
  markers: [{ 
   address: "5278 Plainfield Ave NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49525",
   html: "Grand Rapids - North" 
  }],
  address: "5278 Plainfield Ave NE, Grand Rapids, MI 49525",
  zoom: 9
 });

 $("#map_3").gMap({
  controls: false,
  markers: [{ 
   address: "6991 Kalamzoo Ave SE, Kentwood, MI 49508",
   html: "Grand Rapids - South" 
  }],
  address: "6991 Kalamzoo Ave SE, Kentwood, MI 49508",
  zoom: 9
 });
});
```

**And Related HTML:**

```
<div id="map_1" class="google_map"></div>
<div id="map_2" class="google_map"></div>
<div id="map_3" class="google_map"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use something like gmap in scope of plugin function instead of $gmap in global scope:

http://softm.org.ua/google-map-jquery-plugins/

here at bottom is link to popup with working script. 
Am not sure if there will work other functions.

PS. BTW, -does it allow best-focus on few addresses, then to add few other addresses, without zoom/bounds changes?

Comment: Wow - this looks extremely promising! Thanks for posting back here. I ended up putting all points on the same map, but this could definitely be useful for other applications.

Comment: This is first steps just ... i now redo another google map plugin, seems to focus now on needed point :) This one, was not usefull ... but very nicely programmed inside, btw.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in gMap plugin as it seems that gMap cannot initialize multiple maps on single page that have address lookup. When I changed one or two maps to regular latitude/longitude lookup, it showed these maps fine.

Try opening bug in gMap's issue tracker (if it exists) or reporting it to gMap developer.

Comment: I just realized it was the address lookup issue as well. Bummer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

wow. trickey. The only difference I can see is on the example, it loads the map API then jQuery.
On yours you do it the other way around. Stupid idea maybe...